# Rendering equations with Doxygen and MathJax in CHM file

Tags: latex, doxygen, chm, mathjax

I've got doxygen configured so that I can get MathJax to render equations nicely in the HTML output.  I had hoped that things would magically work with output to a CHM file (which is what I distribute), but unfortunately I was wrong.

Has anyone tried to do this before, and if so, how did you do it?

Comment: Afaik doxygen generates a hhp project?

Comment: I believe it uses HTML Help to generate the chm, so are you proposing that this is actually something where HTML Help needs to be set up to properly render the javascript used for MathJax?

Comment: It is not clear from the question IF you managed to create a CHM at all. My first guess was that you didn't install html help workshop. From your comment I guess you do. Explaining /what/ exactly doesn't work might help

Comment: Sorry about that!  I can create the HTML output that shows the MathJax output, and I can create the CHM file.  However, the CHM file just has a broken image link where the MathJax output should be.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, use a tool (search for chmlib or "chm decompressor") to look inside the CHM, and check all relevant JS scripts and other files are there.

If Doxygen doesn't add all relevant files to the .hhp, it might be possible that the outdates html scanning of HTML help doesn't find and package all references to external files.